# How to show different horizontal bar colors in grouped time series data in Pandas according to a column value (0/1)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, time-series

I have the following sampled data frame from a million rows. It'll show value counts of anomalous rows, a dataframe with only anomalous rows, and the plot.

Input data:

```py
df_sample = pd.DataFrame({
    'AbsoluteTopImpressionPercentage': [0.0,  1.0,  1.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  1.0,  0.75,  1.0,  1.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  1.0,  1.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.5,  0.0,  0.5,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  1.0,  1.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.5,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  1.0,  1.0], 
    'AdFormat': ['TEXT',  'TEXT',  'UNKNOWN',  'UNKNOWN',  'UNKNOWN',  'UNKNOWN',  'UNKNOWN',  'UNKNOWN',  'TEXT',  'TEXT',  'UNKNOWN',  'UNKNOWN',  'UNKNOWN',  'UNKNOWN',  'UNKNOWN',  'UNKNOWN',  'TEXT',  'UNKNOWN',  'TEXT',  'TEXT',  'UNKNOWN',  'UNKNOWN',  'UNKNOWN',  'UNKNOWN',  'TEXT',  'UNKNOWN',  'UNKNOWN',  'UNKNOWN',  'UNKNOWN',  'UNKNOWN',  'UNKNOWN',  'TEXT',  'UNKNOWN',  'UNKNOWN',  'TEXT',  'UNKNOWN',  'UNKNOWN',  'UNKNOWN',  'UNKNOWN',  'UNKNOWN',  'UNKNOWN',  'UNKNOWN',  'UNKNOWN',  'UNKNOWN',  'UNKNOWN',  'TEXT',  'UNKNOWN',  'TEXT',  'UNKNOWN',  'UNKNOWN'], 
    'AdNetworkType1': ['SEARCH',  'SEARCH',  'SEARCH',  'SEARCH',  'SEARCH',  'SEARCH',  'SEARCH',  'SEARCH',  'SEARCH',  'SEARCH',  'SEARCH',  'SEARCH',  'SEARCH',  'SEARCH',  'SEARCH',  'SEARCH',  'SEARCH',  'SEARCH',  'SEARCH',  'SEARCH',  'SEARCH',  'SEARCH',  'SEARCH',  'SEARCH',  'SEARCH',  'SEARCH',  'SEARCH',  'SEARCH',  'SEARCH',  'SEARCH',  'SEARCH',  'SEARCH',  'SEARCH',  'SEARCH',  'SEARCH',  'SEARCH',  'SEARCH',  'SEARCH',  'SEARCH',  'SEARCH',  'SEARCH',  'SEARCH',  'SEARCH',  'SEARCH',  'SEARCH',  'SEARCH',  'SEARCH',  'SEARCH',  'SEARCH',  'SEARCH'], 
    'AdNetworkType2': ['SEARCH',  'SEARCH',  'SEARCH',  'SEARCH_PARTNERS',  'SEARCH_PARTNERS',  'SEARCH_PARTNERS',  'SEARCH_PARTNERS',  'SEARCH_PARTNERS',  'SEARCH',  'SEARCH_PARTNERS',  'SEARCH_PARTNERS',  'SEARCH',  'SEARCH',  'SEARCH',  'SEARCH',  'SEARCH',  'SEARCH',  'SEARCH',  'SEARCH',  'SEARCH',  'SEARCH_PARTNERS',  'SEARCH_PARTNERS',  'SEARCH',  'SEARCH',  'SEARCH',  'SEARCH_PARTNERS',  'SEARCH_PARTNERS',  'SEARCH_PARTNERS',  'SEARCH_PARTNERS',  'SEARCH',  'SEARCH',  'SEARCH',  'SEARCH',  'SEARCH_PARTNERS',  'SEARCH_PARTNERS',  'SEARCH_PARTNERS',  'SEARCH_PARTNERS',  'SEARCH',  'SEARCH_PARTNERS',  'SEARCH',  'SEARCH',  'SEARCH',  'SEARCH_PARTNERS',  'SEARCH_PARTNERS',  'SEARCH',  'SEARCH',  'SEARCH',  'SEARCH',  'SEARCH',  'SEARCH'], 
    'AllConversionRate': [0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0], 
    'Clicks': [0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  4,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  1,  1,  1,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  10,  0,  1,  0,  0,  1,  0], 
    'ConversionRate': [0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0], 
    'Ctr': [0.0,  1.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  1.0,  0.2105,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  1.0,  0.3333,  1.0,  0.25,  0.0,  0.5,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.2326,  0.0,  1.0,  0.0,  0.0,  1.0,  0.0], 
    'Date': ['2021-04-09 00:00:00+00:00',  '2021-04-19 00:00:00+00:00',  '2022-08-24 00:00:00+00:00',  '2021-07-25 00:00:00+00:00',  '2022-07-29 00:00:00+00:00',  '2022-05-27 00:00:00+00:00',  '2022-05-18 00:00:00+00:00',  '2022-07-24 00:00:00+00:00',  '2021-02-05 00:00:00+00:00',  '2021-04-30 00:00:00+00:00',  '2021-07-11 00:00:00+00:00',  '2021-05-24 00:00:00+00:00',  '2022-05-22 00:00:00+00:00',  '2021-07-01 00:00:00+00:00',  '2021-07-11 00:00:00+00:00',  '2022-03-24 00:00:00+00:00',  '2021-05-12 00:00:00+00:00',  '2022-06-14 00:00:00+00:00',  '2021-04-27 00:00:00+00:00',  '2021-01-29 00:00:00+00:00',  '2022-09-08 00:00:00+00:00',  '2021-06-07 00:00:00+00:00',  '2022-05-28 00:00:00+00:00',  '2022-03-26 00:00:00+00:00',  '2021-04-09 00:00:00+00:00',  '2022-05-22 00:00:00+00:00',  '2021-05-28 00:00:00+00:00',  '2022-05-22 00:00:00+00:00',  '2021-07-06 00:00:00+00:00',  '2021-07-14 00:00:00+00:00',  '2021-06-24 00:00:00+00:00',  '2021-03-24 00:00:00+00:00',  '2021-06-03 00:00:00+00:00',  '2022-05-30 00:00:00+00:00',  '2021-03-15 00:00:00+00:00',  '2022-08-05 00:00:00+00:00',  '2021-07-06 00:00:00+00:00',  '2022-03-30 00:00:00+00:00',  '2022-09-07 00:00:00+00:00',  '2021-05-27 00:00:00+00:00',  '2021-06-04 00:00:00+00:00',  '2022-04-16 00:00:00+00:00',  '2022-05-22 00:00:00+00:00',  '2021-07-08 00:00:00+00:00',  '2022-05-26 00:00:00+00:00',  '2021-02-09 00:00:00+00:00',  '2022-04-27 00:00:00+00:00',  '2021-05-06 00:00:00+00:00',  '2021-06-29 00:00:00+00:00',  '2022-06-01 00:00:00+00:00'], 
    'Anomaly': [0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0]
})
```

My code:

```py
df_sample = df_sample.sort_values(by='Date')
df_sample['Date'] = df_sample['Date'].apply(pd.to_datetime)
print(df_sample.Anomaly.value_counts())
print('')
display(df_sample.loc[df_sample['Anomaly'] == 1])

colors=[]
for val in df_sample['Anomaly']:
    if val == 1:
        colors.append('red')
    else:
        colors.append('blue')

# or
#colors = pd.cut(df['Sum'].tolist(), [-np.inf, 10, 20, np.inf],
#                labels=['green', 'orange', 'red'])

#ax = df['Sum'].plot(kind='barh',color=colors)

fig, axs = plt.subplots(figsize=(22, 12))
df_sample.groupby(df_sample['Date'].dt.date)["Clicks"].sum().plot(kind='barh', ax=axs, color=colors)
plt.xlabel("Clicks")
plt.ylabel("Dates")

every_nth = 7
for n, label in enumerate(axs.yaxis.get_ticklabels()):
    if n % every_nth != 0:
        label.set_visible(False)
```

Output:

Now in the output, I want those df_sample.Anomaly rows with value == 1 to be shown in the graph horizontal bars as red instead of blue. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without changing your code too much, you need to create the list of colors on your grouped data which you will plot later.

The line, where I create `out`, I used `max` as aggregation for the column `Anomaly`. In your example data for each group of `Anomaly` there is only only 0's or only 1's. If these values differ you can decide here what you want to do (e.g take first or last, sum them up, min or max)

Then build the list of colors based on the new data in `out['Anomaly']` and plot it based on `out['Clicks']`

```py
df_sample['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_sample['Date'])
df_sample = df_sample.sort_values(by='Date')

out = df_sample.groupby(df_sample['Date'].dt.date).agg({'Clicks' : 'sum', 'Anomaly': 'max'})
print(out)

#collect colors based on that data
colors = ['red' if val==1 else 'blue' for val in out['Anomaly']]

fig, axs = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,8))
out['Clicks'].plot(kind='barh', ax=axs, color=colors)
axs.set_xlabel("Clicks")
axs.set_ylabel("Dates")

every_nth = 7
for n, label in enumerate(axs.yaxis.get_ticklabels()):
    if n % every_nth != 0:
        label.set_visible(False)
```

[image]

Comment: 'out' doesn't have the Anomaly values.

Comment: I updated my answer, have a look again. I think I got your point and fixed it

Comment: Dunno how but your code worked in the original data frame, had to change a bit: colors = ['red' if val==1 else 'blue' for val in df_anomaly['Anomaly']]